# Webscraper Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape each real estate details at this page https://e-leiloes.pt/listagem1.aspx, but it has both a scroll down and a button for further results.

In my opinion, I have to create a scroll down selector to scroll down all results and after that, a link selector for each result. I have already managed to extract data from the details page.

What happens is that scraping begins, but only scrolls three times and then stops but the main page has more than a thousand results.

Thanks for any advice.

[screenshot of webscraper selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l2vy.png)

Comment: You can examine their `InfiniteScroll()` function or call it youself.

Comment: Can i do it within webscraper add selector ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the "Web Scraper" extension itself, but if you can operate that I'm sure you can invoke a function on that page. Maybe there is a custom script you can insert with that extension in order to do that, if not you can either create a simple userscript to do some of that work or create an extension which will be much easier to specialize to specifically scrape that site.